# Unable to import all the records from SQL Server View to HDFS using Sqoop

Tags: sql-server, sqoop

I am unable to import all the records from SQL Server View to HDFS using Sqoop.
SQL Server *VIEW* `v_callDetail` is created using `JOINS` from several other table:

```
CREATE view testdb.dbo.v_callDetail AS
select
 i.callkey,
 i.col1,
 i.col2,
 i.col3,
 i.col4,
 i.inc_datetime_col
from testdb.dbo.callDetail i (nolock)
    inner join [dbo].[tabl2] rt (nolock)
        on i.callKey = rt.id
    inner join [dbo].[tabl3] et (nolock)
        on i.col1 = et.id
    left join testdb.dbo.lob l (nolock)
        on i.col2 = l.id
    left join testdb.dbo.division d (nolock)
        on i.col3 = d.id
    left join testdb.dbo.region r (nolock)
        on i.col4 = r.id;
```

This *v_callDetail* has 350 millions records. But only 20 millions are getting imported.
But when I am importing data from any table, I am able to import all the records.
For instance one table had ~700 million, and all got imported using the same sqoop command given below, and for several other tables as well.
Sqoop command:

```
$> export SQOOP_DELIM=$( printf "\x01" )
$> sqoop import \
$> --options-file /path/to/sqoop_property.txt \
$> -D mapreduce.map.memory.mb=6144 -D mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx6144m -D mapred.job.queue.name=L3_queue -D mapred.job.name="job_Import_sqlServer_View" \
$> --connect jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:1433 \
$> --username u123 --P \
$> --fields-terminated-by ${SQOOP_DELIM} \
$> --map-column-java col1=String,col2=String \
$> --null-string '' --null-non-string '' \
$> --query "select callkey,col1,col2,col3,col4,inc_datetime_col from testdb.dbo.v_callDetail WHERE inc_datetime_col<'2020-02-06 00:00:00' \
$> --delete-target-dir \
$> --target-dir /hdfs/path/to/landing/dir \
$> --hive-drop-import-delims \
$> --split-by callkey \
$> -m 20
```

This is happening with VIEW only.
Do I have to set some SQLServer or Sqoop parameters ?

Comment: Why are you abusing the `NOLOCK` hint here? You know it will cause you to get incorrect results, right?

Comment: that (no lock) is created by the source team (SQL Server team). We are required only to pull the data. I got this *VIEW* DDL from the following command `SELECT definition FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('testdb.dbo.v_callDetail');` Has this **(no lock)** got to do something with partial data pull ?

Comment: It *could*, but more likely the just exasperate the problem. It's use here is clearly be someone that doesn't know the ramifications of it's use.

Comment: FYI [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Try running sqoop eval multiple times to check count of entire table as well as few specific values for inc_datetime_col to see that count of records in view is not changing.
sqoop eval --connect jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:1433 --username u123 --P --options-file /path/to/sqoop_property.txt --query "select count(*) from testdb.dbo.v_callDetail WHERE inc_datetime_col<'2020-02-06 00:00:00' 

Also you mentioned, v_callDetail has 350 millions records but only 20 millions are getting imported. Are 350 million for inc_datetime_col<'2020-02-06 00:00:00 or is it it full view count?

Comment: Its the count for inc_datetime_col<'2020-02-06'.